# Zend_Form empty values problem -html result: <form action="" method="">

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have Zend_Form empty values problem:

My View: I print only part of form elements, because that I not doing  `echo $this->form`

```
  <form  method="<?php $this->escape($this->form->getMethod()); ?>" >

     <label> Title</label>
     <?php
     echo $this->form->title;
     ?>
    <label>Body: </label>
     <?php echo $this->form->body; ?>
  </form>
```

html result:

```
<form  method="">
```

instead

```
<form  method="post">
```

thanks

Comment: Why do you have an empty label?

Comment: I add value to label, thanks erenon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed an echo.

```
<form  method="<?php echo $this->escape($this->form->getMethod()); ?>" >
```